# How to do an assemble-time modulus on constants in ARM assembly language

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to know how to do modulus in arm assembly language

I've tried the code in this page [MOD operator](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0008a/a166_op_mod.htm) in arm website:

```
MOV     R1,#12 MOD 7   ; R1 = 5
MOV     R2,#99 MOD 10  ; R2 = 9
```

but it doesn't assemble.

I'm using the [keil](https://www.keil.com/demo/eval/armv4.htm) assembler.

Comment: Define _"it isn't working"_. You also need to specify which assembler you're using, and whether you want to do a compile-time or run-time MOD operation.

Comment: What have you tried already, and with which toolchain? The ARM documentation should match the ARM toolchain, so I'm guessing you're using something else.

Comment: @michael i updated my question, i hope it's clear now.
ams i didnt try anything, i'm learning arm and i'm testing simple stuff, so when i googled mod it led me to that page i posted in my original post

Comment: You should learn how to make divisions first. Do some research prior to asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the *GNU assembler* (you don't say), then the mod (remainder) operator is `%`, same as C.

The [fine manual is here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Infix-Ops.html#Infix-Ops).

Comment: sry, i didnt know it depends on the assembler, well i updated my question

Comment: Just to be clear, this operator is evaluated at compile time and does not produce an executable modulus operation in ARM assembly code.

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for **runtime modulo instead of assemble-time**, you can do div and mod using two instructions:

```
;Precondition: R0 % R1 is the required computation
;Postcondition: R0 has the result of R0 % R1
              : R2 has R0 / R1

; Example comments for 10 % 7
UDIV R2, R0, R1      ; 1 <- 10 / 7       ; R2 <- R0 / R1
MLS  R0, R1, R2, R0  ; 3 <- 10 - (7 * 1) ; R0 <- R0 - (R1 * R2 )
```

Documentation for [MLS](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasmref/armasmref_Cihihggj.htm), which was designed exactly for this use-case.

Comment: Should note that this is a _run-time_ modulus.

Comment: This answer really belongs in a separate Q&A.  This question's title is about something different so it looks weird to use it as a duplicate target for questions that include how to do runtime modulo.

Answer (score 4):

Keil/armasm spells it `:MOD:`. See the manual http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_Cacechjd.htm